Sorting posts by presence of some particular post tag
I need to make sorting of posts on archive pages (is_archive) using pre_get_posts when sort=trend is pressent in URL.
I would like on top to be sorted posts with tag (post_tag) with ID 55 and after all posts (if any) in current query with that tag to show other posts without that specific tag.
So, in my case it would be like this.

On 1st place is latest published post with tag with ID 55
On 2nd place is post with tag with ID 55
On 3rd place is oldest post with tag with ID 55
On 4th place is latest published post without tag with
ID 55
On 5th place is post without tag with ID 55
On 6th place is oldest post without tag with ID 55
...

I hope you figured out, so basically sorting by presence of tag with ID 55 by date, and after that, any other post(s) without that tag also sorted by date.
I have this function:
function custom_sort_posts($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive()) { // If it is the main query and not in the admin area and it's archive
    if (isset($_GET['sort']) && $sort === 'trend') {
                    $trend_tag_id = pll_get_term(55); // Get tag ID "55" in current language

                    $tax_query[] = [
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        [
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                            'field' => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $trend_tag_id,
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        ],
                        [
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                            'field' => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $trend_tag_id,
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                        ]
                    ];

                    // Sort first by presence of tag, then by publish date
                    $query->set('orderby', [
                        'tag__in' => 'DESC', // Posts with tag "trend" will be on top
                        'date' => 'DESC' // Sort by date, newest first
                    ]);
    }
}

}
It is not working, I get the same sorting of posts as without that.
I hope someone can provide a better function, if it is even possible to do such a sorting of posts?

Nearly identical to your other question; see my answer.
